# How to add facebook video into og:video meta tag?

Tags: facebook, video

It is easy to put youtube video into meta tag. But I am trying to put a facebook page video into the og:video meta tag. However, the video doesn't show up. Any idea?

```
    <!-- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#media -->

    <meta property="og:url"              content="http://homemaidapp.com/apps/rfsn/test2.php" />
    <meta property="og:title"            content="test title" /
    <meta property="og:description"      content="test descritpion" />
    <meta property="og:image"            content="http://homemaidapp.com/apps/rfsn/image/sample_fb_share.png" />

    <meta property="og:type"             content="video" />
    <meta property="og:video"            content="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=1013127335421377_990687704332007">
    <meta property="og:video:type"       content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width"      content="500">
    <meta property="og:video:height"     content="281">

    <meta property="fb:app_id"           content="348767955164988"><!-- facebook app id for tracking or advanced function -->
```

Comment: Well first of all, `https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=1013127335421377_990687704332007` is not the address of a video, but of an HTML document that _embeds_ a video. And secondly, Facebook does not allow you to use images on their CDN for the `og:image`, so I doubt they will allow it for videos.

Comment: well...I found the facebook video download link can be used. So, the problem is fixed. but I run into another problem now. When I shared this page to facebook, it looks like a youtube post which is fine... but when I start to play the video, all the description gone....for youtube, the description will be moved to the bottom of the video when the video is playing.

Answer (score 2):

I found the facebook video download link can be used to put into the og:video and I changed the og:video:type to video/mp4. It works.

Comment: Does Facebook auto play it's own video?