# How do I add a youtube video to my site's meta tag?

Tags: meta-tags

This post says it is easy to add a youtube video but I could not find any tips.

[How to add facebook video into og:video meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493608/how-to-add-facebook-video-into-ogvideo-meta-tag)

Google says you should not add iframe tags to the head as on:

"Don't use invalid elements in the

No element other than the aforementioned is permitted by the HTML specification in the head. Common elements that appear in the head, rendering it invalid are:

```
iframe
img
```

We strongly recommend that you don't use these invalid elements in the head, but if you must, place these invalid elements after the ones you want Google to see. Once Google detects one of these invalid elements, it assumes the end of the head and stops reading any further elements in the head."

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/valid-page-metadata

I do see search results that indicate a site a video alongside. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

just use the iframe tag and copy the youtube url into src it should look something like this

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```